# Symfony2 timestampable include update of related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create an application using Symfony2, and I've come up against something I can't figure out. I have an entity called Company and another called Address, with a Many to Many relationship (should be One to Many but I think this is the way Symfony/Doctrine handles it). i.e. each Company could have one or more Addresses. I have set up the Gedmo's Doctrine Extensions and I'm using timestampable on both entities. I have set up a form which updates both linked entities, but what I would really like is to be able to timestamp Company if Address gets updated, as it is the owner of the two.

Does anyone know if timestampable can do this or what I may have done wrong?

You can see my Company class here:

```
<?php
// src/Amber/AtsBundle/Entity/Company.php
namespace Amber\AtsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
//...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Company
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Company
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="company_addresses",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 **/
private $addresses;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->addresses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;
```

The Address class, not a lot to see

```
<?php
// src/Amber/AtsBundle/Entity/Address.php
namespace Amber\AtsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 private $id;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;
```

I don't think you need to see setters and getters but let me know

Controller

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class CompaniesController extends Controller
{

    public function editAction(Request $request, $companyID)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $company = $em->getRepository('AmberAtsBundle:Company')->find($companyID);

    $passExist = 'Yes';

   $form = $this->createForm(new CompanyType(), $company, array("pass_exists" => $passExist));

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->flush(); 

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('amber_ats_companies_edit', array('companyID' => $company->getId())));
        }
    }    
}
```

Would be grateful for any help...

Comment: please review my comment and comment if anything unclear otherwise accept the answer please :)

Comment: Another tip: Please have a look at @ParamConverter to clean up your controller -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose timestample does not check for changes on associated entites.

The solution is to create a bi-directional one-to-many relation between Company and Address with Company being the owning side.

**Company**

```
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="company", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $addresses;
```

**Address**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="adresses")
 */
protected $company;

public function getCompany()
{
   return $this->company;
}

public function setCompany($company)
{
   $this->company = $company;

    return $this;
}

// now the the tricky part

public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;

    if  ( $updated > $this->company->getUpdated() )
    {
       $this->company->setUpdated($updated);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You can use many-to-many if multiple companies can have the same addresses and loop over all associated companies like this:

```
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;
    foreach ($this->companies as $company) {
       if  ( $updated > $this->company->getUpdated() )
       {
           $this->company->setUpdated($updated);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Adjust your mapping annotations accordingly but i guess you get the idea ...

Comment: Thanks, it's a great solution, my problem is I was planning on using the Address entity to serve others such as Person. So I was hoping to be able to timestamp Company if that is the context Address was updated in, or update another entity such as Person if that was the context

Comment: In this case add a non-persistent property ( and getter/setter ) context to your Address entity and set it ( in __construct or with dependency injection ) as a hidden input in your AddressFormType. Include a switch in setUpdated on your  Address entity like ... $this->{$this->context} = $updated; ... if construct the form with context included bindRequest will make Address have context 'company' or 'Person' and only these will be updated! But please accept my answer and phrase a new question if you want more detailed information :)

Comment: Your answer got me thinking, and I think I've sorted what I wanted, thanks for your help. The solution was to add some code in the controller, to flush the changes, compare dates, update 'updated' if necessary and then flush changes again. see below

Comment: if ($form->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database 
                $em->flush(); 
                foreach ($company->getAddresses() as $key => $address) {
                    if ($company->getUpdated() < $address->getUpdated()){
                        $company->setUpdated(new \DateTime("now"));
                    } 
                }
               $em->flush(); 
             }

Comment: yes that'S another solution but it involves repeating the procedure in all of your controller'S imagine you would have 100 relations then it would be easier to have the form/entity handle that stuff for you. a form listener might be helpful here aswell :)